# Deprecated errors while converting app compatible with new IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdk

I am developing an application.

The main thing is that i have to make compatible it with latest IOS.So, I just want to know

- whether i need to install latest xcode sdk for that ? or
- i can make it with sdk lower than latest?

Thanks for Helping .

Comment: There's a way in the compiler settings to turn off the "deprecated" warnings, if you want to do that.  (Don't recall the details, though.)

Answer (score 2):

The only reason you would need to use the latest SDK would be to take advantage of the latest iOS 5 changes (new API's and features like Storyboarding).

But anything that is built under older SDK's (such as iOS 4.3) is supposed to run just fine on iOS 5. In reality, that isn't always the case though.

Comment: In reality, anything built to run on iOS 4 and earlier that doesn't use a pure xib approach to the UI will probably fail somehow on iOS 5. And likely some that do use only xibs are broken. I'd guess that the odds of an iOS 4 app of any complexity running on 5 is less than 50%.

Answer (score 0):

You can/should make the target SDK be the lowest "target" device you want to handle (eg, 3.2), though you can compile/build with either iOS 4 or iOS 5. If you don't build with Xcode 4, though, you'll need a physical iOS 5 device to test on. (Good to have one anyway, but it's inconvenient having to do all your testing on a device.) If you do build on Xcode 4 be sure to test both against iOS 5 and a lower version (if you want compatibility with a lower version).